# How to use url_for with flask_restx?

Tags: flask-restx

I can use *url_for* in a **flask** 2.0.1 template like

```html
<!-- flask-template.html -->
<button onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'testimport') }}';" >Import</button>
```

along with

```py
@app.route('/import/images')
def testimport():
  return "ok"
```

but I cannot do it with a *resource* in **flask-restx** 0.5.1.

```py
api = Api(app, version='1.0',
          title='The Restx API',
          description='An API to initiate basic operations')
ns_detect = api.namespace('detect', path='/', description='Detection')
@ns_detect.route('/detect/recording')
class DetectRecording(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {"status": "ok"}
```

Can anybody please explain, how to correctly use *url_for* in the flask-restx case above?

```html
<button value="{{ url_for( 'ns_detect.DetectRecording') }}">1</button> <!-- can't build -->
<button value="{{ Api.url_for( 'DetectRecording') }}">2</button> <!-- Api undefined -->
<button value="{{ api.url_for( 'DetectRecording') }}">3</button> <!-- api undefined -->
<button value="{{ url_for( 'ns_detect.DetectRecording') }}">4</button> <!-- can't build -->
<button value="{{ url_for( 'api.DetectRecording') }}">5</button> <!-- can't build -->
<button value="{{ url_for( 'ns_detect.DetectRecording.post') }}">6</button> <!-- can't build -->
```

btw: I have installed
Werkzeug 2.0.3
Jinja2 3.1.2

Answer (score 3):

After some trial and error, I figured out, which magic key is required to make `url_for` work with *flask-restx*:
it's a combination of namespace and a modified classname.
Example:

```py
ns = api.namespace('xxx', path='/', description='some description')  
@ns.route('/some/endpoint')
class DoSomething(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {"status": "ok"}
```

then use `url_for({{ 'xxx_do_something' }})`.

Maybe the flask-restx documentation would benefit from such an example..

Answer (score 1):

When using `flask.Blueprint` and `flask_restx.Namespace` together, you have to reference the blueprint, the namespace, and the class name of the route in your call of `flask.url_for`.

The format, as [x y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003134/x-y) described, is "blueprint.namespace_route_name". Remember that the camelcase in the class's name is deconstructed to snake_case. (RouteName -> route_name, in the example above)

## Example

The example below has the API registered as a `flask.Blueprint` and the `flask_restx.Api` object registered has two namespaces (Users and Books) each with a single GET routes. Both routes return their corresponding endpoints using `flask.url_for`

```py
    
    # Create a Flask app
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # Create 'api' BLUEPRINT for the API, named "api"
    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
    
    # Create an instance of the Api class
    api = Api(blueprint)
    
    # Define the 'users' NAMESPACE
    users_ns = Namespace('users', description='Users related operations')
    
    # Define the 'UsersList' ROUTE in the 'users' NAMESPACE
    @users_ns.route('/')
    class UsersList(Resource):
        def get(self):
            return {'UsersList_url': url_for('api.users_users_list')}
    
    # Define the 'books' NAMESPACE
    books_ns = Namespace('books', description='Books related operations')
    
    # Define the "Books" ROUTE in the 'books' NAMESPACE
    @books_ns.route('/')
    class Books(Resource):
        def get(self):
            return {'Books_url': url_for('api.books_books')}
    
    # Register the namespaces with the API
    api.add_namespace(users_ns)
    api.add_namespace(books_ns)
    
    # Register the blueprint with the Flask app
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

for me worked following,

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, url_for, make_response
...
blueprint = Blueprint('blueprintname', __name__, 
url_prefix='/api/v1.0')
api_extension = Api(
  blueprint,
  title='My title',
  version='1.0',
  description='My description',
  doc='/documentation'
)
...
namespaceAdmin = Namespace('admin')
api_extension.add_namespace(namespaceAdmin)
@namespaceAdmin.route('/password')
class ResetPassword(Resource):
  def get(self):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
    return make_response(render_template('password.html'),200,headers)
```

and in template,

```
<form action="{{ url_for('blueprintname.admin_reset_password') }}" method="post">
</form>
```

use this syntax in url_for,

> blueprint.namespace_classname

for ex.

```
blueprint = Blueprint('blueprint', __name__)
myNamespace = Namespace('namespace')
class ResetPassword(Resource):
```

in template (classname should be dashed below)

```
{{ url_for('blueprint.namespace_reset_password') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set the endpoint argument in the route method, like this:

```
@ns_detect.route('/detect/recording', endpoint="recording")
```

After that, define blueprint (allow you more scalability) and api objects, like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(bp)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

This is just fast exemple but you can set much more value information about your blueprint and api objects, like prefix, description, version, etc.

Then, call url_for passing the endpoint value:

```
<button value="{{url_for('api.recording')}}">X</button>
```

I strongly suggest to read the [flask-restx docs](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scaling.html?highlight=blueprint#use-with-blueprints) about this topic